# No selecciona la base de datos... mysql_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, mysql

```
<div class="columnader">
        <?php
        session_start();
        $servidor="localhost";
        $usuario="root";
        $pass="";
        $based="pruebastarento";
        $conser=mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $pass);
        $conbd=mysql_select_db($conser,"pruebastarento") or die (mysql_error());


        $cadena="SELECT * FROM `tornillos`";
        $run=mysqli_query($conser,$cadena);

        echo"<TABLE id='tlista'>";

        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<th> ID </th>";
        echo"<th> Nombre </th>";
        echo"<th> Tipo </th>";
        echo"<th> Descripcion </th>";
        echo"</tr>";

        echo"<tr scope='col'>";
        echo"<p>";

        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($run,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
             echo"<TR align=center>";
             echo"<TD>".$fila['ID_TOR']."</TD>";
             echo"<TD>".$fila['NOM_TOR']."</TD>";
             echo"<TD>".$fila['TIPO_TOR']."</TD>";
             echo"<TD>".$fila['DESC_TOR']."</TD>";
             echo"</TR>";
        }
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</tr>";

        mysqli_close($conser);

        echo"</TABLE>";

        ?>
```

Comment: Los parámetros son a la inversa , `mysql_select_db("pruebastarento",$conser)` primero el nombre de la base de datos y luego la Conexión , además tener en cuenta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php

Comment: Estas usando una función desactualizada para consultar los datos ([ver Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/intro.mysql.php)). Recomendaría no perder tiempo tratando de corregir un código que tendrás que sustituir tarde o temprano por MySQLi o por PDO.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pero los errores que me marca son de parametros

Comment: Yo tengo un problema y es que no considero correcto ayudar a hacer funcionar un código que a la larga podría ser peligroso, como es este caso. Debido a que estás usando funciones obsoletas, en cuanto el código funcione podrías tener una Inyección SQL. PHP recomienda por eso usar las extensiones PDO o MySQLi. Yo optaría por PDO, y si quieres, [aquí tienes una clase ya hecha que puedes usar](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO). Te facilitará mucho las cosas y los datos estarán más seguros.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hola prueba esto `mysql_select_db("nombre_BD");` de esta forma me funciona a my